# Hardware virtualization reported as supported by CPU but turned off. Or is it?

Tags: cpu, bios, virtualization, vmware

I have a AMD A8-5600K running on a A78M-E (FM2+ ) motherboard. I use VMWare Player a lot, and just noticed via Speccy that virtualization is supported by the CPU but turned off. How do I turn it on? I could not find an option for it in BIOS. Also, will it make a big difference in performance? Thanks. I am running Windows 7 Pro.

[update]

I found the SVM option in BIOS, and it is already enabled. Further, I ran "coreinfo -v" and it says this:

```
AMD A8-5600K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
AMD64 Family 21 Model 16 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
SVM             *       Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
NP              *       Supports AMD nested page tables (SLAT)
```

Is Speccy reporting incorrectly?

Comment: Did you run speccy while one of your VMs was running?

Comment: No, the VM is turned off currently.